# How does Javascript's indexOf() resolve references

Tags: javascript, arrays, reference, specifications, ecmascript-5

I was confusing myself a little with a thought experiment and now I'm looking for some advice. Its about ECMAscript references and the `Array.prototype.indexOf()` method.

Lets start easy:

```
var container = [ ];
// more code
container.push( 5 );
container.push( 7 );
container.push( 10 );
```

---

So now we pushed some "*primitive values*" into our ECMAscript array (whether or not that statement is true I'll come back for), at least I imagined it like this so far. A call to

```
container.indexOf( 7 );
```

will return `1` as expected. The big question I'm having is, if `.indexOf()` really compares the primitive value or if in reality a `Number()` object is created + stored and its **reference** is getting compared. This becomes a little more obvious if we re-write that like so:

```
var a = 5,
    b = 7,
    c = 10;

var container = [ ];

container.push( a );
container.push( b );
container.push( c );

container.indexOf( b );
```

---

Until this point, one could still easily argue that all `.indexOf()` needs to do is to compare values, but now lets look at something like this:

```
var a = { name: 'a', value: 5 },
    b = { name: 'b', value: 10 },
    c = { name: 'c', value: 15 };

var container = [ ];
// more code
container.push( a );
container.push( b );
container.push( c );
```

Here, we filled that container array with *object-references* and still, `.indexOf()` works as expected

```
container.indexOf( b ) // === 1
```

while a call like this

```
container.indexOf({ name: 'b', value: 10 });
```

obviously returns `-1` since we are creating a new object and get a new reference. So here it must internally compare references with each other, right?

Can some ECMAscript spec genius confirm that or even better link me some material about that ?

A side question on this would be if there is any possibly way to access an internally stored object-reference within a *lexicalEnvironment* respectively *Activation Object*.

Comment: If this works anywhere similar to other languages, then `indexOf` works on object hashes where objects usually have different values and primitive objects usually have a constant hash based on their value (for integers, this is very often just the integer value itself). So two int objects `5` and `5` both have the hash `5` and as such are “the same”.

Comment: I started writing an answer, but then it turned into a blog post so I stopped and got discouraged from re-writing it. But if you're interested: http://pastie.org/4828933

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It boils down to `indexOf()` comparing against each array property in turn using the same algorithm as the `===` operator.

The relevant section of the ECMAScript 5 spec is section 15.4.4.14, step 9, section b (highlighting mine):

> If kPresent is true, then
>
> > i. Let elementK be the result of calling the [[Get]] internal method of O with the argument ToString(k).
> >
> > ii. Let same be the result of applying the **Strict Equality Comparison Algorithm** to searchElement and elementK.
> >
> > iii. If same is true, return k.

References:

- [indexOf()](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.14)
- [Strict Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.6)

Comment: nice heads-up thanks. However, the *strict equality comparison* described there does not describe how to deal with objects in general ? Looks like they only describe for numbers, strings, booleans and null/undefined values. Also, I'm curious about the first section aswell which says, "*calling toString()*" on the argument. If that really is the native `toString` then all objects should return *object Object* no ?

Comment: @jAndy: the `ToString(k)` bit is referring to the property name, not the value. The strict equality comparison section does describe the algorithm completely. See step 7 in 11.9.6: *"Return true if x and y refer to the same object. Otherwise, return false."*.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is guaranteed across all ECMAScript implementations or not, but the [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) states that it uses strict equality to make the comparison (===). As such this would exhibit the behaviour you describe, comparing by values on primitives, but by reference on objects (see [strict equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Using_the_Equality_Operators)).

Comment: Even `==` uses comparison by references for objects. So it's nothing to do with strict equality

Comment: I'm not saying it's *because of* strict equality. I'm saying it's actually using strict equality and that's consistent with the behaviour he describes.

Answer (score 0):

@Tim Down is right. `indexOf` does strict comparison. I am giving a demonstration of this by overriding `valueOf` function

```
var MyObject = function(n, v){
   this.name = n;
   this.value = v;
}

MyObject.prototype.valueOf = function(){
    return this.value;
}

var a = new MyObject("a", 5);
var b = new MyObject("b", 10);
var c = new MyObject("c", 15);

var container = [ ];

container.push( a );
container.push( b );
container.push( c );

console.log(b == 10); // true
console.log(container[1] == 10); // true

console.log(b === 10); // false
container.indexOf(10); // -1
```